# Flutter - Icon selection on user click

Tags: flutter, dart, user-interface

So what I am trying to accomplish is when the user selects the "icon" from the list of icons, I want the selected icon to move to the center and the other icons to disappear.  I hope that makes sense.  I want it to be a smooth transition for the user.  How do I do that?  Here is the code and screenshots:

"Add Event Page" code:

```js
import 'package:evnt_app/tiles/category_tile.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:google_fonts/google_fonts.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

import '../data/evnt_data.dart';
import '../models/category_model.dart';

class AddEventPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const AddEventPage({
    super.key,
  });

  @override
  State<AddEventPage> createState() => _AddEventPageState();
}

class _AddEventPageState extends State<AddEventPage> {
  // Show Date Variable
  DateTime _dateTime = DateTime.now();

  // Show Date Picker Method
  void _showDatePicker() {
    showDatePicker(
      context: context,
      initialDate: DateTime.now(),
      firstDate: DateTime.now(),
      lastDate: DateTime(2030),
    ).then((value) {
      setState(() {
        _dateTime = value!;
      });
    });
  }

  bool isClicked = false;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Consumer<EvntData>(
      builder: (context, value, child) => Scaffold(
        // AppBar
        appBar: AppBar(
          elevation: 0,
          backgroundColor: Colors.red.shade400,
          title: Text(
            'Add Event',
            style:
                GoogleFonts.poppins(fontSize: 20, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
          ),
        ),
        body: Column(
          children: [
            // CHOOSE A CATEGORY HEADER
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 20.0),
              child: Text('Choose an Icon',
                  style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                      fontSize: 18, fontWeight: FontWeight.w600)),
            ),

            // CHOOSE AN ICON LIST VIEW
            Container(
              height: 150,
              child: Expanded(
                child: ListView.builder(
                  scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                  itemCount: value.categories.length,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    Category individualCategory = value.categories[index];
                    return CategoryTile(
                      categories: individualCategory,
                    );
                  },
                ),
              ),
            ),

            // EVENT DETAILS SECTION
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 20.0, right: 20.0),
              child: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: [
                  // Event Title Header
                  Row(
                    children: [
                      Text(
                        'Event Name',
                        style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                            fontSize: 16,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                            color: Colors.red.shade400),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                  // Event Name Text Field
                  TextField(
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      hintText: "Enter Event Name",
                      hintStyle: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                          fontSize: 18, fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
                    ),
                    style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                        fontSize: 18, fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
                  ),

                  const SizedBox(height: 25.0),

                  // Event Date Header
                  Text(
                    'Date',
                    style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                        fontSize: 16,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                        color: Colors.red.shade400),
                  ),
                  // Event Date
                  TextField(
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      hintText: "Enter Date",
                      hintStyle: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                          fontSize: 18, fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
                    ),
                    style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                        fontSize: 18, fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
                  ),

                  const SizedBox(height: 25.0),

                  // Event Time Header
                  Text(
                    'Time',
                    style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                        fontSize: 16,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                        color: Colors.red.shade400),
                  ),
                  // Event Date
                  TextField(
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      hintText: "Enter Time",
                      hintStyle: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                          fontSize: 18, fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
                    ),
                    style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                        fontSize: 18, fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
                  ),

                  const SizedBox(height: 25.0),

                  // Event Location Header
                  Text(
                    'Location',
                    style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                        fontSize: 16,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                        color: Colors.red.shade400),
                  ),
                  // Event Location
                  TextField(
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      hintText: "Enter Location",
                      hintStyle: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                          fontSize: 18, fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
                    ),
                    style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                        fontSize: 18, fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
                  ),

                  const SizedBox(height: 50.0),

                  // Add Event Button
                  Center(
                    child: Container(
                      width: 150,
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50.0),
                          color: Colors.red.shade400),
                      child: MaterialButton(
                        shape: const RoundedRectangleBorder(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                            Radius.circular(50.0),
                          ),
                        ),
                        minWidth: 150.0,
                        height: 50.0,
                        onPressed: null,
                        color: Colors.black,
                        child: Row(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                          children: [
                            Text(
                              'Add',
                              style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                                  fontSize: 18,
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                                  color: Colors.white),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

"Category Tile" code

```js
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:google_fonts/google_fonts.dart';
import '../models/category_model.dart';

class CategoryTile extends StatefulWidget {
  Category categories;

  CategoryTile({super.key, required this.categories});

  @override
  State<CategoryTile> createState() => _CategoryTileState();
}

class _CategoryTileState extends State<CategoryTile> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Row(
      children: [
        // ICON & NAME SELECTOR SECTION
        Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 25.0, left: 10, right: 10),
          child: GestureDetector(
            onTap: () {},
            child: Column(
              children: [
                // Choose Category Image
                Container(
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50),
                      color: widget.categories.iconColor),
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
                    child: Image(
                      image: widget.categories.iconImagePath,
                      width: 50,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: see https://docs.flutter.dev/ui/animations/hero-animations

Comment: That is nice but I don't want it to go to a different page.  I just want the icon selected to stay the same size, the other icons to disappear all on the same page

Comment: you can try using `PageController`, you can pass a controller to it and animate it to center tapped element